# Prove uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\arctan \frac{x}{x^2 + k^3}$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that this series converges uniformly

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\arctan \frac{x}{x^2 + k^3}, x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I tried the following:

$$
|{\arctan \frac{x}{x^2 + k^3}}| \leq  \frac{{|x|}}{x^2 + k^3} \leq \frac{{|x|}}{k^3}
$$

But this series doesn't converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. Also i tried:

$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}f_k(n)| \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f_k(n)|$$

But for every $k \in \mathbb{N} :\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f_k(n)| = +\infty$.

What can we use to prove uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You went too far on your first string of inequalities. You have that

$$\frac{|x|}{x^2+k^3} \leq \frac{1}{2k^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

from calculus. This then leads to a uniform bound.

Comment: could you please explain why this inequality is true?

Comment: @envygrunt from calculus. You would expect that quantity as a function of $x$ to have a maximum because $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x)\to 0$ as $|x|\to\infty$. Just find it.

Comment: okay, thank you for response